# call a java webservice on html page without using javascript

Tags: java, html, web-services

I want to know how to call a java webservice on html page without using javascript ?
Thanks

Comment: The only other way I know is to use a form submission to make POST requests

Comment: What does the web service do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a web service you need to make an HTTP request.

If the service accepts input formatted as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, and returns something that can be rendered in a human readable form by browsers, you can use a `<form>` (although this does mean leaving the page or using frames).

Otherwise you need to use a programming language.

JavaScript is the standard method for doing this in a webpage, but since you reject that in the question, I'll list some of the (less well supported) alternatives.

- Flash (requires plugin)
- Java applet (requires plugin)
- VBScript (requires IE, possibly even old-IE)
- ActiveX control (requires IE and low security settings)
- PerlScript (requires IE (possibly old IE) and a plugin (possibly no longer distributed by ActiveState who wrote it)).

The options that require plugins are not supported on all platforms. You can certainly kiss goodbye to iOS for any of them.

I'd strongly recommend ditching the "no JavaScript" requirement though.